# Print Spooler API - AddForm example

Tags: c++, printing, print-spooler-api

I am trying to make a AddForm function using C++ Windows.h's Print Spooler API. I haven't find any C++ examples or couldn't figure out solution, so I wanted ask your help.

**My code should done same as in this picture:**

[image: My code should done same as in this picture]

**Source Material**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/addform
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-size
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12229/Adding-Custom-Paper-Sizes-to-Named-Printers-2
- [Use PrintSpoolerAPI function SetForm() in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850433/use-printspoolerapi-function-setform-in-c-sharp)

**Code input:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Winspool.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    LPHANDLE hPrinter = NULL;
    OpenPrinter(
        NULL,
        hPrinter,
        NULL
    );  // No critical error here: "hPrinter could be "0"

    FORM_INFO_1 exampleform;
    exampleform.Flags = 0;
    exampleform.pName = (LPWSTR)"0A"; // No critical error here: "Cast between semantically different string types. Use of invalid string can lead to undefined behaviour."
    exampleform.Size.cx = 1260 * 1000;
    exampleform.Size.cy = 891 * 1000;
    exampleform.ImageableArea.left = 0;
    exampleform.ImageableArea.top = 0;
    exampleform.ImageableArea.right = exampleform.Size.cx;
    exampleform.ImageableArea.bottom = exampleform.Size.cy;

    cout << exampleform.pName; //output as: "00007FF68EFA9C24"

    AddForm(hPrinter, 1, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&exampleform)); // No critical error here : "hPrinter could be "0"

    //C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\paperApp\x64\Debug\paperApp.exe (process 16792) exited with code 0.
}
```

**Problem:**
The code looks good, but nothing really happens.

Thank you all for your responses!

Comment: What is [AddForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/addform) returning? If zero, then what is [GetLastError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror)?

Comment: AddForm returns 0. I looked at GetLastError, which returns 6, which means the handle is invalid. My guess is that the error is in the OpenPrinter function.

Comment: If OpenPrinter returns zero, call GetLastError.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you defining your own [FORM_INFO_1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/form-info-1)? Just use the header provided by Windows:

```
#include "Winspool.h"
```

Then fix the differences from your definition:

```
FORM_INFO_1 exampleform;
exampleform.Flags = 0;
exampleform.pName = (LPWSTR)"MyName";
exampleform.Size.cx = 1260 * 1000;
exampleform.Size.cy = 891 * 1000;
exampleform.ImageableArea.left = 0;
exampleform.ImageableArea.top = 0;
exampleform.ImageableArea.right = exampleform.Size.cx;
exampleform.ImageableArea.bottom = exampleform.Size.cy;
```

Then fix the error you're getting with a C-style cast:

```
test = AddForm(hPrinter, 1, (LPBYTE)&exampleform);
```

Or a [C++-style cast](https://cplusplus.com/articles/iG3hAqkS/):

```
test = AddForm(hPrinter, 1, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&exampleform));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Westgate for your reply! I still got couple challenges with the code. I made post about it in this topic.

Comment: Like most Windows APIs, if AddForm() returns false, you can call [GetLastError()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387064/313445) to find out what the error is. This is basic Windows programming and debugging. If you don't know these things then you need to find some [tutorials](https://riptutorial.com/winapi/example/8521/error-reported-with-additional-information-on-failure) or books on the topic.